# NFS Mount hostname listed as something different from what was entered

Tags: linux, nfs, mount, rhel7

Assume there exists a nfs server `foo1`.
A client machine contains a hosts file with the following entry

```
172.168.1.2  foo1 foo2 foo3
```

which points to that server and a few aliases.

Also assume that `/exports/dir1` and `/exports/dir2` are exported by `foo1`.

If client attempts to mount using the following commands:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/dir1 && mount -t nfs foo2:/exports/dir1 /mnt/dir1
mkdir -p /mnt/dir2 && mount -t nfs foo1:/exports/dir2 /mnt/dir2
```

The command `mount -l` will show

```
foo2:/exports/dir1 on /mnt/dir1 type nfs4 ... 
foo2:/exports/dir2 on /mnt/dir2 type nfs4 ... (notice the host isn't foo1)
```

After unmounting, and reversing the order of the mount commands, it will result in `foo1` being shown as the host for both entries in a `mount -l`.

```
#Unmount and remount reversing the order of hosts
umount /mnt/dir1
umount /mnt/dir2
mount -t nfs foo1:/exports/dir1 /mnt/dir1
mount -t nfs foo2:/exports/dir2 /mnt/dir2
```

The command `mount -l` now shows...

```
foo1:/exports/dir1 on /mnt/dir1 type nfs4 ... 
foo1:/exports/dir2 on /mnt/dir2 type nfs4 ... (notice the host isn't foo2)
```

Firstly, is anyone else able to observe this behavior?

Secondly, is there some way to instruct mount or the nfs client to maintain the hostname as entered for nfs mounts when running any subsequent `mount -l` command to check what is mounted?

Just for the sake of full disclosure.
I am currently running RHEL 7.1 Server on the NFS client.
The NFS host is running RHEL 6.1 Server.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the `/exports/dir1` and `/exports/dir2` on the same filesystem or are those mountpoints serving different filesystems?

Comment: They are different partitions on the same drive.

Comment: It seems to be related to how NFSv4 treats the exports the exports. It should work out of the box if you mount them with NFSv3, or you have to export each single `/exports/dir*` with an `fsid`. Not sure if that is really your issue.